# changeMove on binary/boolean planning variable - optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

My planning variable is Boolean.

I want to use changeMoves only, and I want to use a cartesian product of changeMove to have a coarser move. This is in my planner config:

```
    <unionMoveSelector>
        <changeMoveSelector/>
        <cartesianProductMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector/>
            <changeMoveSelector/>
            <changeMoveSelector/>
            <changeMoveSelector/>
            <changeMoveSelector/>
        </cartesianProductMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
```

How can I avoid to have "move not doable" half of the time?

At the moment, I often have for example:

```
Move index (5) not doable, ignoring move (... {false -> false})
```

Basically, I want a move that consists of switching the boolean state, which is always doable (`false` becomes `true` and `true` becomes `false`).

This is even worse for cartesian products of changeMoves, since I assume the move is ignored when one of the changeMove is not doable... So with n changeMoves, I have only a 1/2^n chance of getting a doable cartesian...

Do I have to create a custom move or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This might be [a small design flaw](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-589). Currently, isDoable is not handled as a move filter (and I intend to change that at some point in the long-term future if possible). If it were, it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (untested - let me know here if it works): On the `<changeMoveSelector/>` add a `MoveFilter` to filter the non doable moves. That way they won't get into the cartesian selector, which might improve your efficiency.

If this workaround works, it's also a proof on how we should fix [PLANNER-589](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-589) upstream.

Comment: Thanks, I will try when I have the chance. For now I have implemented a custom "FlipMove" which reverse the boolean value and is always accepted.

Comment: Intresting. Do try it and let me know - I 'd be interested if that filter makes a big difference in your use case, as it would make an argument to refactor isDoable accordingly.